# Specifying Azure Kubernetes virtual network address space

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-service

How do I specify the address space of the virtual network created when provisioning a Kubernetes cluster? If that is not possible, how do I move the cluster to a different address space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time is not possible. However, you can use ACS Engine to do this. Engine is where our dev work. Vnet support is there now and will come to ACS on the future.

See http://github.com/azure/acs-engine

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this. I followed the walkthrough here: https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/kubernetes.md and combined it with the following example: https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/tree/master/examples/vnet.